# iPad Pro and Adobe Creative Cloud

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, creative-cloud, ipad

Can you use the Adobe Creative Clouds apps, the desktop version, on an iPad Pro?  Possibly through mirroring the display ( desktop to iPad)?

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE. Tthis is a question better suited for the Adobe forums

Comment: @Ryan this actually helped quite a bit!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> Can you use the Adobe Creative Clouds apps, the desktop version, on an iPad Pro?

No, they have separate apps for that.

- [Adobe Comp](http://www.adobe.com/products/comp.html) Like Indesign
- [Adobe Sketch](http://www.adobe.com/products/sketch.html) Like Illustrator
- [Adobe Fix](http://www.adobe.com/products/fix.html) Like Photoshop
- [Adobe Mix](http://www.adobe.com/products/mix.html) Like Photoshop

Note: You will probably need an Adobe CC subscription to use those apps.

> Possibly through mirroring the display ( desktop to iPad)?

You could possibly use something like Teamviewer. Usually an Ipad would be used as a drawing tablet rather than mirroring the desktop to the Ipad Pro.

Comment: I've tried the apps on the iPad, and I don't particularly care for them.  I saw somebody in one of my classes this past semester using the desktop apps on her iPad Pro, and I wish I had asked her.                  I've looked at TeamViewer before but I don't think I was satisfied with it.  Using the iPad as a drawing tablet is what I've been finding, so maybe that's what I'm looking for.  Thank you!